# Why Paper.js create path with path data looks different from importSVG()?

Tags: paperjs

As the code below and result image, the data used is exactly the same, yet, the result looks different. Any idea?

```
var pathData = 'M2253.35,991.1c0,133.79 -108.46,242.25 -242.25,242.25c-133.79,0 -242.25,-108.46 -242.25,-242.25c0,-133.79 108.46,-242.25 242.25,-242.25c23.13166,0 45.50614,3.24217 66.69379,9.29687c-21.41569,17.08959 -28.99235,39.21284 -22.72998,66.36974c4.51912,19.57983 1.84302,36.54082 -8.0283,50.88297c-11.35414,-3.52242 -23.42334,-5.41957 -35.9355,-5.41957c-66.9,0 -121.13,54.22 -121.13,121.12c0,66.9 54.23,121.12 121.13,121.12c66.89,0 121.12,-54.22 121.12,-121.12c0,-22.51871 -6.14433,-43.60075 -16.8476,-61.66191c16.43974,-5.80075 28.58821,-17.95876 36.44543,-36.47404c10.9747,-25.86154 30.32412,-39.3221 58.04826,-40.38167c27.40806,39.25569 43.48392,87.00946 43.48392,138.51762zM2059.24903,879.92754c9.90684,-14.35675 12.59943,-31.33927 8.07776,-50.94757c-6.31362,-27.37914 1.43923,-49.6419 23.25853,-66.78829c44.38054,15.40874 82.89584,43.35999 111.30338,79.61122c-27.35983,1.25299 -46.48201,14.704 -57.36653,40.35304c-7.847,18.49121 -19.97411,30.64167 -36.38133,36.45138c-12.57072,-16.80058 -29.40217,-30.22764 -48.89181,-38.67979z';

var path = project.importSVG('<path d="' + pathData + '"/>');
var path2 = new Path(pathData);
 
path.fillColor = 'pink';
path2.fillColor = 'orange';

path2.position += [0, 500];

view.translate([
    -1700,
    -650
]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path data that you are providing includes multiple path so you shouldn't use the `Path` constructor, which is made for a single path, but the `CompoundPath` constructor, which is made for multiple paths.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the corrected code.

```
var path2 = new CompoundPath(pathData);
```